# Change jQuery based on window size for BXslider Not Working

Tags: jquery, slider, responsive-design, bxslider

I have installed the BX slider on the current site I am working on, this being a responsive site, I would like to change some options if the browser is at a certain width. The code I have written below breaks my layout for the slider though, any suggestions why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        if (width < 701) {

            $('#slidebx').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal',
                infiniteLoop: true,
                speed: 500,
                pause: 5000,
                auto: true,
                pager: false,
                controls: true,
                displaySlideQty: 1,
                moveSlideQty: 1
            });

        } else {

            $('#slidebx').bxSlider({
                mode: 'horizontal',
                infiniteLoop: true,
                speed: 500,
                pause: 5000,
                auto: true,
                pager: false,
                controls: true,
                displaySlideQty: 4,
                moveSlideQty: 4
            });
        }
    });​

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the width variable you're checking in your if statement set some where?

Try this:

```
if ($(document).width() < 701) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: That was it, missed the variable. For some reason I thought that was a standard. Still new to writing jQuery. Appreciate the help!